# SSE Comparison Intrinsics - How to get 1 or 0 from a comparison?

Tags: c, if-statement, comparison, sse, intrinsics

I am trying to write the equivalent of an if statement with SSE intrinsics.

I am using `__m128 _mm_cmplt_ps(__m128 a, __m128 b)` to do the comparison a < b, and this returns `0xffffffff` or `0x0` if the comparison was respectively true or false. I would like to convert these values into 1 and 0. In order to do this, is it correct to implement the logical "and" `__m128 _mm_and_ps(__m128 c , __m128 d)`, where `c` is the result of the conversion and `d` is, e.g., `0xffffffff`?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Is there an absolute value intrinsic? (and no, d would have to be 1) Logical right shift by 31 would also do.

Comment: What do you plan to do with the `0` and `1`?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen What do you mean? Is my implementation wrong? And what do you mean with logical right shift? Sorry, I am a noob. :)

Comment: @Mysticial I want to multiply them with another value, in order to change this according to the comparison.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a conditional move?

Comment: 0xffff and 0xffff is 0xffff. 0xffff and 0x0001 is 1, 0 and 1 is 0. I'm just suggesting that 0xffffffff happens to be -1 and it's absolute value is 1. Also if 0xffffffff is shifted right 31 bits, it's 1 and 0 remains 0. There maybe other easy formulas/expressions to convert -1 and 0 to 1 and 0. Actually yes. -1*-1 = 1 and 0*0 = 0. and also 0-n works. Logical right shift of 00001100 in binary by 2 is 00000011. Logical right shift of 1xxxxx by 5 is 000001. (Arithmetic right shift would copy the leftmost bit and would be of no use in this case)

Comment: @Mystical Wonderful example for an XY problem. +1 for asking exactly the right question to spot it

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're comparing to get a `1` or a `0`, then multiplying by another number. That is essentially this:

```
c = (a < b) * d;
```

which is the same as this:

```
c = 0;
if (a < b)
    c = d;
```

This is also known as a conditional move.

If that's what you want, then you don't need the `0` or the `1`. Just AND the result of the compare directly with the number you will multiply with.

```
__m128 c = _mm_cmplt_ps(a,b);
c = _mm_and_ps(c,d);
```

This works because the comparison returns either all `0`'s or all `1`'s. So ANDing them with the result will either zero it, or keep it entirely.

It was intentionally designed that way. There's no need for a multiplication.

Comment: in this example, a and b are __m128, right?
or can they be integers too?

Comment: @nimbus3000 No they can't. These are SIMD instructions. They don't work on GPRs.