# Is there a Intel SIMD comparison function that returns 0 or 1 instead of 0 or 0xFFFFFFFF?

Tags: intel, sse, simd, intrinsics

I'm currently using the intel SIMD function: `_mm_cmplt_ps( V1, V2 )`.
The function returns a vector containing the results of each component test. Based on if V1 components are less than V2 components, example:

```
XMVECTOR Result;

Result.x = (V1.x < V2.x) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0;
Result.y = (V1.y < V2.y) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0;
Result.z = (V1.z < V2.z) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0;
Result.w = (V1.w < V2.w) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0;

return Result;
```

However is there a function like this that returns 1 or 0 instead? A function that uses SIMD and no workarounds because it is supposed to be optimized + vectorized.

Comment: No, if you need that you can just `andps` with a vector of `_mm_set1_epi32(1)` to clear the upper bits.  Or integer subtract from `0`.  But if you want to conditionally increment counters, use `psubd` to do `counter -= cmp_result` because `x -= -1` is `x += 1`, instead of negating or masking first.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the 1 or 0, that you can't do with -1 or 0?

Comment: Or did you mean returning the bit-pattern for `1.0f`?  Generally you don't actually need that, see [SSE Comparison Intrinsics - How to get 1 or 0 from a comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13256983).

Comment: Another approach could be to use `_mm_srli_epi32` to shift the result right by 31 bits, which would avoid the need to have a register holding ones.

Comment: @chtz I'm using 0 or 1 in an array.

Comment: @JasonR I know about that, but that's a workaround, I'm trying to do maximum optimization.

Comment: You use it in an array of what (`float`, `int32`, `int8`)? And what do you do with the array afterwards?

Comment: @PeterCordes Isn't there a way to do this exact same thing in assembly and return 1 instead of UINT32MAX?

Comment: @chtz It's a XMVECTOR BOUNDS[2] array, 4 components of float, the array contains MIN and MAX values of a box, I could reverse the array and do 1- the return value I get from _mm_cmplt_ps. I guess I could load the variable as an int since it's a float comparison which gives me -1 instead of 0xFFFFFFFF. But that's alot of work cause I need to change a lot of code

Comment: @Xardas110: It's not a workaround, it's a solution to your problem. There is no single assembly instruction that will do the comparison and return `0` or `1`, period. The others are asking deeper questions to find out "do you **really** need `0` or `1`". If you do, then you can't get away with a single instruction.

Comment: Please try to explain your actual problem in the question, not your attempt to solve one part of it (IMO, you have an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) -- it looks more like you need a blend (but your last comment is a bit vague)

Comment: @chtz Peter gave me the answer I was really looking for, the rest of you have just been asking me "do you really need 0 or 1", so I just tried to explain my problem to you briefly, I will consider this as solved now.

Comment: Even though it's *possible* to do whatever you're doing by creating an actual vector of 0 or 1, it's probably more efficient *not* to.  I'd still suggest you describe what you want it for, unless you're happy with what's probably a sub-optimal solution.  There is no asm instruction that compares floats and directly produces a vector of `0` or `1`.  AVX512 compares produce a packed bitmap, pre-AVX512 compares produce vector elements of all-zero or all-one bits.

Comment: Related: [AVX2 float compare and get 0.0 or 1.0 instead of all-0 or all-one bits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43699476) which uses `min` instead of `and`; there might be some advantage there for more general cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write that function yourself. It’s only 2 instructions:

```
// 1.0 for lanes where a < b, zero otherwise
inline __m128 compareLessThan_01( __m128 a, __m128 b )
{
    const __m128 cmp = _mm_cmplt_ps( a, b );
    return _mm_and_ps( cmp, _mm_set1_ps( 1.0f ) );
}
```

Here’s more generic version which returns either of the 2 values. It requires SSE 4.1 which is almost universally available by now with [97.94% of users](https://store.steampowered.com/hwsurvey), if you have to support SSE2-only, emulate with _mm_and_ps, _mm_andnot_ps, and _mm_or_ps.

```
// y for lanes where a < b, x otherwise
inline __m128 compareLessThan_xy( __m128 a, __m128 b, float x, float y )
{
    const __m128 cmp = _mm_cmplt_ps( a, b );
    return _mm_blendv_ps( _mm_set1_ps( x ), _mm_set1_ps( y ), cmp );
}
```

Comment: Note that blendv is SSE4.1, but yes this is what you'd do if you can't optimize away actually generating float `1.0` or uint32 `1`

Comment: Commenting since the suggested edit queue is full: while `_mm_cmplt_ps()` and `_mm_and_ps()` are one instruction each,  `_mm_set1_ps()` is usually at least two. So the start of this answer should probably say three intrinsics and four or more instructions.

Comment: @ToddWest When the argument is a compile-time constant like `1.0`, `_mm_set1_ps` usually compiles into no instructions. Specifically, when the code is not inlined, the `_mm_and_ps` instruction can take the second argument directly from memory, like `andps xmm0, xmmword ptr[…]`, the compiler places the data in readonly section of the binary. When the code is inlined and the function is called in a loop, the vector is loaded only once outside of the loop.

Comment: @Soonts, I've never seen that in disassembly. (Many loops also spill registers, in which case the load once assumption may not hold.)

Comment: @ToddWest This might be compiler-specific. In 75% of cases when I read assembly, the binary was made by VC++ in release config for AVX2 ISA. Also, my loops tend to not spill registers; when they do, I view it as a sign that I inlined or unrolled too much, and when possible I adjust C++ code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The DirectXMath no-intrinsics version of `_mm_cmplt_ps` is actually:

```
    XMVECTORU32 Control = { { {
            (V1.vector4_f32[0] < V2.vector4_f32[0]) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0,
            (V1.vector4_f32[1] < V2.vector4_f32[1]) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0,
            (V1.vector4_f32[2] < V2.vector4_f32[2]) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0,
            (V1.vector4_f32[3] < V2.vector4_f32[3]) ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0
        } } };
    return Control.v;
```

`XMVECTOR` is the same as `__m128` which is 4 floats so it needs the alias to make sure it's writing integers.

I use `_mm_movemask_ps` for the "Control Register" version of DirectXMath functions. It just collects the top-most bit of each SIMD value.

```
int result = _mm_movemask_ps(_mm_cmplt_ps( V1, V2 ));
```

The lower nibble of `result` will contain bit patterns. A 1 bit for each value that passes the test, and a 0 bit for each value that fails the test. This could be used to reconstruct 1 vs. 0.